# Substring Search in redis value

Tags: redis, memcached

I have a mongoDB table for emp like

```
empid:String;
name:String;
phone:String;
Address:String;
```

I was thinking to store this in redis cache with empid as key and rest as value If, so, how do search with a substring for the employee with partial name/phone/address?

Comment: Could you give an example. It's not clear how you want to search... do you want to search based on name, phone etc..

Comment: Did you check the Redis module RediSearch (https://redisearch.io)

Comment: @VikramRawat: Assume I have entry where key is empId : 123 and Value ( name:John Smith, phone : 9833221166 ) then I need to make a search by name like john* or *smith or number like 9833*

Comment: @GuyKorland: Thanks for the input. I think, this is what I was looking for. I will take a look and see whether it matches my need. Thanks again

Comment: Got it @RaghuVallikkat ... as suggested by GuyKorlan RediSearch is the right solution..